# Swing java, close specific window when menu is used

Tags: java, swing

I have a class which creates a menu with all of the menuItems etc, I then have many UIs which have a JMenu in which I give the JMenu from the first class. My problem is that the menu has many items which open other UIs, how do I make a check so that one is opened, the current window is closed?

A very short version of what I do is :

Menu:

```
public Menu()
{       
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    }
    public JMenuBar makeMenu()
    {
         return menuBar;
     }
```

UI :

```
public UI()
{
 JMenuBar menu = Menu.makeMenu();
 }
```

Note this is just to see the idea, the code is far more complicated but would be useless to show. The reason why I do this is that I have such a gigantic menu that it would add a huge amount of repeatable code to all UIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every window has its own menubar then you can use the `ExitAction` class found in [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I modified the code so that it works for anyone with my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code that camickr provided, I make a perfect fix for this problem by just turning the visibility off of the first frame while the other one loads, this way the system doesn t close since ExitAction code was closing before anything else appeared. The code is as it follows :

```
for (Window frame : Window.getWindows())
        {
            if (frame.isActive())
            {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help people

Comment: There should be no need to change the ExitAction. If you want the frame to be invisible when you click the "X" button then you should be using `frame.setDeafaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` when you create the JFrame.

Comment: well, I found this way to also work very well so I hope if anyone else finds this they will see the code and the links you put and find them useful, thanks again.